# What is wrong with my Dlookup syntax?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have four Tables: Artist, Album, Tracks, and Import.  I am basically making my own I-Tunes, which frustrates me to use.  Anyway, my issue is that many artist release albums with the same name, Greatest Hits, ect.  I bring ITunes into Access via excel to my Import Table.  Adding the artist is easy, and so is the Albums.  I need to bring in the Tracks/Songs, but I need to update my Import Table with the new Album IDs, via using Dlookup with more than one criteria. I have tried with/without brackets, quotes, double quotes, ect.  I keep getting a syntax error?

```
Private Sub Command88_Click()
Dim Count As Integer
Dim ArtistLookupID As Integer
Dim AlbumTitleName As String

Count = 0
 With Me.Recordset
  .MoveFirst
 Do While Not .EOF
 ArtistLookupID = Me.[Artist ID]
 AlbumTitleName = Me.[Album Title]
 MsgBox "" & ArtistLookupID & " " & AlbumTitleName
 Dlookup("[Album ID]", "[Album Table]", "[Album Title] = AlbumTitleName AND [Artist ID] = 'ArtistLookupID'")
 Count = Count + 1
    .MoveNext
  Loop
End With
MsgBox "records processed=" & Count
End Sub
```

Anybody?

Comment: This is NOT how I input this!  It is harder to post a question here than writing the VBA code I'm having trouble with. :(

Comment: You need to mark the code with code tags - someone got it for you

Answer (score 2):

```
Dlookup("[Album ID]", "[Album Table]", "[Album Title] = '" & AlbumTitleName & "' AND [Artist ID] = " & ArtistLookupID & "")
```

should work, you were including your variable names in the string i think

Edit: No quoting of the numeric ID.

Answer (score 1):

*DLookup* returns a value or *Null*, so you probably have something like this in mind:

```
Count = Count + Abs(Not IsNull(Dlookup("[Album ID]", "[Album Table]", "[Album Title] = AlbumTitleName AND [Artist ID] = 'ArtistLookupID'")))
```